# Why Each positive real number is a cluster point? what are the elements of that set?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to get some intuition of Limit point in the context of topology.

wiki gives this definition

> In mathematics, a limit point (or cluster point or accumulation point)
>   of a set $S$ in a topological space $X$ is a point $x$ that can be
>   "approximated" by points of $S$ in the sense that every neighborhood of
>   $x$ with respect to the topology on $X$ also contains a point of $S$ other
>   than $x$ itself.

and this example

> A sequence enumerating all positive rational numbers. Each positive real number is a cluster point.

take $\pi$ as the example. what are the elements of this set $S$, of which this cluster point $\pi$ "approximated" by points of $S$?

I've searched this [claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) through [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Each%20positive%20real%20number%20is%20a%20cluster%20point%22), and got nothing.

any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: The example doesn’t make sense since they don’t tell you of what set the real numbers are cluster points

Comment: Your example is missing a lot of information. First off, it doesn't explicitly state what the set $S$ is supposed to be. Secondly, it doesn't explicitly state which topology you define on the real numbers. Under the standard topology, if you let $S = \mathbb{R}$, then $\pi$ is a cluster point, but if $S = (0, 1)$, then $\pi$ is not a cluster point.

Answer (score 1):

If you're quoting something, quote it properly. "This example" is given under the illustration with the following description:

> A sequence enumerating all positive rational numbers. Each positive real number is a cluster point.

Namely, each real number is a cluster point of the sequence of all the rational numbers. This much is not hard to prove, by the density of the order and by the density of the rationals in the real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, the set is {the sequence of all the rational numbers}, is it?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. And I suppose that they meant even more by considering this specific enumeration as a sequence, rather than just a set. But to be fair, every enumeration of the rational numbers would work equally well.